Regex.Replace in VB.net with regex replacement value
I have a file where i have several recurrence of this
div.1 
div.2
div.3

and so on
I want to replace with div1 , div2 , ...
In my case both pattern and replacement are regular expression
This is the code I wrote
newstr = Regex.Replace(strFile, "div\.\d","div\d")

But it is replacing as following:
div.1  div\d
div.2  div\d

and so on
Any suggestions?
Regex is finding the pattern in the whole file but it is replacing it incorrectly as if replacement is considered as text and not regex.
I have tried in replacement value :  $1 , div\d+$ both same result

You could create 2 capture groups (div)\.(\d) and use $1$2 in the replacement.

Try:
(?<=div)\.(?=\d)

and replace with empty string.
See: regex101
Your issue is that you match the whole string and replace it with the same literal string div\d. This way you only match the literal . and keep your number in place as you "do not touch" it.

Explanation:

(?<=div): ensures literal div before
\.: the literal dot is matched and also
(?=\d): a number must follow


Another way would be use a match evaluator:
newstr = Regex.Replace(strFile, "(div\.\d)", Function(m) m.Value.Replace(".", ""))

(The dot in the regex needs to be escaped, the dot in the ordinary string replace needs no escape.)
